Error code Invalid Template in Forms to Planner flow
I have a flow on Power Automate that creates a Planner sticker when a Form is filled out. The sticker includes data from the Form, including images uploaded.
I created the flow 4 months ago and it worked great, but now out of seemingly thin air an error happened, and no pictures are uploaded to the Planner sticker. The flow still goes through and the Planner sticker is created, but without the images.
The error code in the Parse JSON:
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'Required property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'.
The schema of the Parse JSON:
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {},
            "size": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "referenceId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "driveId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "uploadSessionUrl": {}
        },
        "required": [
            "name",
            "link",
            "id",
            "type",
            "size",
            "referenceId",
            "driveId",
            "status",
            "uploadSessionUrl"
        ]
    }
}

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated :)
I've looked around at other similiar issues, but none of them seemed to fix my issue:
https://community.powerplatform.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=fc6b55ac-d3ac-4209-9420-a430885c9919
Microsoft Power Automate - error with flow - Action 'Parse_JSON' failed
https://www.encodian.com/blog/fix-the-invalidtemplate-unable-to-process-template-language-expressions-in-action-in-microsoft-flow/

Do not post code or error messages as image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors why.
